# Flex Tree, Slelecteditem == XML(node);... BUG?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

when i selected a XML node to tree by doing... i am using flex SDK 3.5 it was working fine in SDK 3.

---

```
tree.selectedItem=XML(node);
```

and then get..
    trace(tree.selectedItem.toString());

### i get error that object is null...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your cast to `XML` is yielding a null.

Try this...

```
var x = node as XML;
trace(x.toString());
```

If you halt the debugger at the line before and inspect `node`, what type is it?  My bet is that `node` and `XML` are not compatible types and the above will throw the same error.

Comment: that is not the issue the thing was working perfectly in sdk 3, i have even tried to assign the item of which tree is made. but of no use.
'tree.selectedItem=XML(node);'
no item is selected...

Answer (score 0):

actually its bug in Flex SDK 4.0 ,,, you can assign using callLaterFunction().

Comment: Could you add little bit more information about the bug, like for instance a link to the tracker.